# Test Recorder and Xamarin Forms - Id not available for UITest

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uitest

I have been trying to run Test Recorder against Android and iOS apps created with Xamarin Forms. When I click on a control in Test Recorder I do not see an Id placed in the C# file generated, just the class type.

I decided to remove Test Recorder from the equation and try and get basic UI Tests running against a Xamarin Forms Android app.

I downloaded a demo app from here:

```
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingUITest/
```

It should have everything in  place to work correctly against UITest including StyleIds and code in the MainActivity to map the StyleIds to ContentDescriptions.

I ran tree in the REPL terminal session to inspect the screen hierarchy and it appears to show no ids for the controls that should have them.

```
>>> tree
[[object CalabashRootView] > PhoneWindow$DecorView]
  [ActionBarOverlayLayout] id: "decor_content_parent"
    [FrameLayout > ... > Platform_DefaultRenderer] id: "content"
      [ButtonRenderer]
        [Button] label: "MyButton",  text: "Click me"
      [LabelRenderer]
        [FormsTextView] label: "MyLabel",  text: "Hello, Xamarin.Forms!"
  [View] id: "navigationBarBackground"
  [View] id: "statusBarBackground"
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The StyleIds are in that output... See the "MyButton" and "MyLabel"?  Those are the StyleId values.  Have you tried running the selector to see if you can select from those?

Comment: Thanks Dylan - I can see in the output that the StyleId of MyButton has been converted to a label of MyButton.  After digging further I see that StyleId gets converted to a AccessibilityIdentifier for iOS and a ContentDescription for Android and I'm guessing these are surfaced as label. My issue is that although I can access these programatically, TestRecorder does not generate .Marked() when I click on a control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xamarin Forms the StyleId is just essentially a placeholder that you use to transfer over to the native counter part.

For Android make sure you have this in MainActivity.cs

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ViewInitializedEventArgs e) => {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.StyleId))
                {
                    e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.StyleId;
                }
            };
```

In iOS do this

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, ViewInitializedEventArgs e) => {
                if (null != e.View.StyleId)
                {
                    e.NativeView.AccessibilityIdentifier = e.View.StyleId;
                }
            };

            LoadApplication(new App());

#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
// requires Xamarin Test Cloud Agent
Xamarin.Calabash.Start();
#endif

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Then you should start seeing your Ids come through for your Xamarin Forms Elements.

Comment: I have the code you mentioned in place in the MainActivity and am relatively happy the native counter parts are being generated. Test Recorder however does not seem to recognise these and will not generate a .Marked for controls with a StyleId but only for buttons and even then using the button caption

Comment: Are you saying the Id's aren't coming through for Buttons but other elements are ok?

Comment: StyleId doesn't get converted to an Id but to a AccessibilityIdentifier for iOS and a ContentDescription for Android. Test Recorder should identify these and generate a .Marked for them but does not. It does generate a .Marked for buttons but using the button caption and not the StyleId

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with the Id's (StyleId's aren't coming across). To me I can't see anything other than its a preview tool and you are most likely running up against a bug. If you can do a REPL in the standard UITests and see all the StyleId's come through then you will need to contact someone at Xamarin. I'm just asking to see who you need to contact. Though its afternoon in SF and might not get a response until tomorrow.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/xamarin-test-cloud is going to be your best bet. Someone from the TestCloud team will see it and look at it. I'm not that familiar with Test Recorder either so there may be something obvious we are overlooking.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I posted on forums.xamarin.com/categories/xamarin-forms before seeing your suggestion. Will cross post on test cloud if I get no replies there

Comment: If you don't get any response, let me know and I can give you email of someone at Xamarin, maybe over private DM and not on SO though :)

Comment: Update - the latest version of Test Recorder (0.8.1.1) properly generates .Marked against the StyleIds

Comment: Great to hear. You find in preview software Xamarin seem to be quite helpful in implementing feedback given, especially when the audience is quite low and hence not much noise coming from the community.